# Instagram Expired Media Links

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-api

Anybody knows how to fix as issue with expired instagram media links ? There is a way to fetch permalink of posts thumbnail?

I was using to add /media/?size=m to the post URL to get the post thumbnail, but starting from 24 October 2020, fetching the permalink like this https://www.instagram.com/p/Bt3QrphggBw/media/?size=m is not more supported.

Any workaround that is not using Facebook API ?

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question, it seems like that method doesn't work anymore and you will need to register an App with facebook and do an oEmbed query

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/oembed#app-token-rate-limits